# Как отрыть статику в express , по заданному пути

Tags: файлы, express, static

Работаю с **nuxt** и **serverMiddleware**(express).

---

Есть такое древо папок: `api/public/` и в каталоге `public` есть еще пару каталогов по типу `folder1` , `folder2`, `folder3` и т.д. В каждом каталоге `folder` есть `index.html` и статика для него (css,img,js.и т.д.)
Сервер получает переменную, которая показывает , какая папка должна открыться и какая статика должна грузится.

---

**Проблема заключается** в том, что сервер отправляет правильный `index.html` , но статику с этой папки НЕ грузит. (ниже код expressa).

```
var open    = res.body.config.folder; // получаю из вне, не важно как.

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/' , open)));


  app.get('/', (req, res)  =>  {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/', open, '/index.html'));
  });
```

Почему статика не отдается?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил проблему. Кому интересно.
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/' , open)));` нужно вызвать в app.get